# How to send and receive sms while using GPRS in QUECTEL modem M95?

Tags: gsm, gprs

I am using QUECTEL M95 modem to connect the server using gprs . And the modem has facility to send and receive test messages .In my project both the situation occurs . By default in programming ip address been set, but there are chances for updating the ip address by sms . Wheather it is possible to send sms during gprs mode? If possible how ? Please suggest me how to do.

Comment: A while ago I compiled a list of basic commands to start with for Quectel modules: [Quectel Module Quickstart Guide](http://blog.tyg-res.tk/2017/09/quectel-module-quickstart-guide.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. If you are using Transparent mode (AT+QIMODE=1) you need to switch to Normal mode (AT+QIMODE=0) and you can send SMS using AT+CMGS regardless of active gprs connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the normal command mode (not to switch to transparent mode).

- `AT+QINDI=1` - to receive data with poll command
- `AT+QIRD` - poll received data
- `AT+QISEND` - send data
- `AT+CMGS` - send SMS
- `AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"` - poll new messages